# Replace string to the left of value and to the right of quote character

Tags: powershell

I have a text file **content.txt**:

```
Some other text 1
"one" : "Text To Replace1:/Text To Stay.133" 
Some other text 2
"five" : "Text To Change2:/Another Text To Stay.50" 
Some other text 5
```

I came up with the following script:

```
$SRCFile = "K:\content.txt"
$DSTFile = "K:\result.txt"
$Text2Replace = "YabaDaba.du:/"

get-content $SRCFile |
ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ".*:\/", $Text2Replace } | Out-File $DSTFile
```

It works almost okay, but it selects the entire line to the left of the ":/" string. I want it only to select the text to the previous quotation mark (excluding it):

[image: Desired selection]

What regex value should I use to point the above script to select only the text up to previous quotation mark? I've been trying Regex101.com, especially LookBehind, but I couldn't come up with any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?<=.+: ").*:\/` might do what you're after. In this case you can also read the file as single multi-line string (hence the use of [`-Raw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3#-raw) in the code) and the use of the [`(?m)` flag (**Multiline mode**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-7.0).

See https://regex101.com/r/3CXaOI/1 for details.

```
$Text2Replace = "YabaDaba.du:/"

(Get-Content $SRCFile -Raw) -replace '(?m)(?<=.+: ").*:\/', $Text2Replace |
    Out-File $DSTFile
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I wanted to take a Powershell course, but I see that without knowing regular expression really well, it makes no sense. Every single Powershell problem I have - I cannot solve it without regex. Thank you again.

Comment: @KolesGit I'm happy to help. Note that my regex knowledge is very basic to be honest, I'm not good at it tho I agree is very very useful in some circumstances. Also, taking a PowerShell course to get better at it without understanding regex is perfectly possible, being good at PowerShell doesn't require you to be a regex expert! If you like it just go with it, its a very fun an useful language